# ODOO 12 : show field of model “purchase.order” in form view of “account.invoice”

Tags: field, odoo, odoo-12, purchase-order

I added commission field in purchase order model and i want to show it in account invoice when i click on "create bill". below is my code but it doesn't work, I hope somebody can help me. Many thanks in advance.

```
class ConfirmComm(models.Model):
  _inherit = "purchase.order"
  commission = fields.Float(string='Commission', required='true', default=0)

      @api.multi
      def action_view_invoice(self, cr, uid, order, context=None):
        if context is None:
          context = {}
        journal_id = self.pool['account.invoice'].default_get(cr, uid, ['journal_id'], context=context)['journal_id']
        if not journal_id:
          raise UserError(_('Error!'),
                          _('Please define purchase journal for this company: "%s" (id:%d).') % (
                            order.company_id.name, order.company_id.id))
        invoice_vals = {
          'name': order.partner_ref or '',
          'origin': order.name,
          # 'type': 'in_invoice',
          # Sale order id as source_id
          # 'source_id': order.id,
          'reference': order.partner_ref or order.name,
          'account_id': order.partner_invoice_id.property_account_receivable.id,
          'partner_id': order.partner_invoice_id.id,
          'journal_id': journal_id,
          'commission': order.commission,
          # 'invoice_line': [(6, 0, lines)],
          'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
          # 'comment': order.note,
          'payment_term_id': order.payment_term_id or False,
          'fiscal_position_id': order.fiscal_position_id,
          'date_invoice': context.get('date_invoice', False),
          'company_id': order.company_id.id,
          'user_id': order.user_id and order.user_id.id or False,
        }
        _logger.info("KTR this is commissionTest $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$ %d", order.commission)
        invoice_vals.update(self._inv_get(cr, uid, order, context=context))
        return invoice_vals
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this field to model `account.invoice`, too, because there is no direct relation between `purchase.order` and `account.invoice` to use a related field or something fancy. To see that field in the invoice form view, you have to add it there, too (as usual).

The rest of your code should be okay, because setting the value by using in it `purchase.order.action_view_invoice()` would be the next important part, but you've already done that ;-)

Comment: i already added it in account_invoice. The problem that odoo still execute the action_view_invoice of purchase.py. Ithink that action_view_invoice is not a method to create invoice but i didin't find the function for doing that.

Comment: there is how i added the commission field in  account.invoice model:                                       
 _inherit = 'account.invoice'

    commission = fields.Float(string='Commission', required='true', default=0)

Comment: You should add the Odoo Version tag to your question, because it has changed a lot in the last few versions.

Comment: in tags odoo 12 does not exist

Comment: IIRC the process of creating purchase invoices is fully on the `account.invoice` model, [here](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/35d4a8ccce8f3a34701d231e17a324cbbf5abfab/addons/purchase/models/account_invoice.py#L89-L117) the magic is happening.

Comment: can you explain to me please, in this example what i will do?

Comment: i was resolved the problem, I overrided the "action_view_invoice" and just added in the context the created field : 'default_commission': self.commission

Comment: Yes that can be one solution ;-)